# I'm using version 1 of Facebook SDK and I'm still getting a Scope error for not using public_profile instead, What Can I do?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a IOS app using version 1 of facebook SDK and I still get the message Scope Error sometimes while trying to log in,

According to [this document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading) I'm not supposed to use the new version of forceful if I specify I'm using the previous version via parameter, until April 30th, 2015.

Like this:

```
FB.init({
  appId      : '{app-id}',
  version    : 'v1.0'
});
```

What can I do?

Comment: Did you create your app after 4/30/2014? Then it doesn't matter that you specified v1.0 because you are not allowed to use v1.0

Comment: Well the app was created long ago, I just made that change recently so it could still keep running.

Comment: Was it active before 4/30/2014? If it wasn't active you will also be forced into API v2.0

Comment: Yes it was also active before that date, I checked.